# Programatically add a gridViewrow in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, datagridviewrow

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "AbC";
row.Cells[1].Value = 123;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Previously I used to add new rows using above code. But now It gives  error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the grid has at least two columns and at least one row? Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: ` DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone(); ` this line gives error

Comment: how will it contain a row when we are adding it programatically ??

Comment: _"how will it contain a row when we are adding it programatically ?? "_ ...  this is true. So how could you "clone" a row that isn't there? ... `DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();` ... ? ...

Comment: then how it is working on a different form. So what's the proper way to add row programmatically ?

Comment: I can only guess that the other code HAS at least one row in the grid. Is the grid’s `AllowUserToAddRows` property set to `true`? There a few ways you can add rows and it depends on if the grid uses a data source. If the grid has no data source and there are at least two columns in the grid, then the code… `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(“ABC”, 123);` … should work.

Comment: thanks for the help,The problem was I unchecked the Enable Adding property in gridview and one can not add row programmatically to data bound gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first entry you need to have a row in your datagridview. If you are not allowing the user to add new rows manually that means there is no row to clone. Then you allow user to add new rows first that will create an empty row to enter data then you will be able to clone that one. Later you can disable adding new rows if you want

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=true;
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "AbC";
row.Cells[1].Value = 123;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=false;
```